# Delete all Rows (Except for Row 1) Before " TH Value"

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is to delete all rows before the green highlight "TH Value".

[image: IMG1]

I've tried almost everything with very little success. I definitely need assistance.

```
Sub Search_Range_For_Text()
Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("b1:b100")
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "After Upd") > 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 0).Value = "TH Value"
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

            MsgBox "Scroll down to find TH Value which is highlighted green.  Check field notes to verify if there was a check shot"
        Exit For
      End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

This image represents the outcome I am trying to achieve:

[image: IMG2]

Comment: Your 2 pictures look the same to me? Neither appear to correspond to your stated problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Comment: Avoid using implicit ActiveSheet reference. Use`For Each cell in ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheetname").Range("b1:b100")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteBelow()
    Dim cell As Range
    '// Set find format: green color
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior
        .Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) '//green color
    End With
    '// Set 'SearchFormat = True' to use FindFormat
    Set cell = Range("B:B").Find(What:="*", SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        If cell.Row > 2 Then
            '// Delete all rows beneath found cell (down to the last sheet row)
            Rows("2:" & cell.Row - 1).Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "No cell was found.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! Please view my new post.

Comment: Heyy Johnyl.  Compile Error, but it looks right to me.  Any sugesstions?

Answer (score 0):

So it solved the problem I think.

Once I blocked the " If Not cell Is Nothing"  then it started working.

Sub DeleteBelow()
    Dim cell As Range
    '// Set find format: green color
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior
        .Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) '//green color
    End With
    '// Set 'SearchFormat = True' to use FindFormat
    Set cell = Range("B:B").Find(What:="*", SearchFormat:=True)
    **'If Not cell Is Nothing Then** ' Blocked this statement 
        If cell.Row > 2 Then
            '// Delete all rows beneath found cell (down to the last sheet row)
            Rows("2:" & cell.Row - 1).Delete
   Else
        'MsgBox "No cell was found.", vbExclamation
   End If

End Sub